# OS X app with bundled OpenJDK created, notarized and installed by install4J fails to start

Tags: install4j

I create dmg with OpenJDK bundled for a Java app using install4j 8.0.2. Without notarization it runs fine on non-Catalina and Catalina with GateKeeper disabled. (The non-bundled AND notarized version runs fine on Catalina.)
However when notarized on launching the following message in a dialog appears:

> “jre.bundle” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Bin.

Pressing Cancel gives another message dialog repeating it.
Cancelling again gives:

> An internal error occurred (error code: Could not load JRE from The bundle “OpenJDK 11.0.1” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources..)

I have no idea how to resolve this.

While searching for clues found the following bits:
- a `java -version` of the bundled java gives the same error message
- notarization log does not show any errors
- OpenJDK [has a bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223671) that could easily be related to this, but my log contradicts with this

Comment: Please try with AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.5. You have to configure the JDK provider on the General Settings->JRE Bundles step.

Comment: Left default JDK release as 'AdoptOpenJDK', have choosen 'openjdk11/jdk-11.0.5+10' in the Select Release dialog, and set 'Generate a JRE bundle' in the Media cofiguration. I can see in the logs that the corresponding JDK is downloaded, bundled, dmg is sent in for notarization, whose log contains no error or warning. Same result finally on launching the app.

Comment: What is the output of codesign -vvv <path to DMG>?

Comment: codesign -vvv test_openjdk11.dmg 
test_openjdk11.dmg: valid on disk
test_openjdk11.dmg: satisfies its Designated Requirement

Comment: Please send a link where this installer can be downloaded to support@ej-technologies.com